# Flash drag strange behavior

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a fancy movie clip (with text and other movie clips inside it)
that I want to drag

I can only drag internal parts of the movie clip but not the whole movie clip.

My NOT working example:

http://www.internetmotors.lv/temp/testgame_5.swf

http://www.internetmotors.lv/temp/testgame_5.fla   (cs5)

Code:

```
drag_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag);
function clickToDrag(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.startDrag();
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);
function releaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.target.stopDrag();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answering my own question:

it seems i need to use
event.currentTarget.startDrag();

instead of:
event.target.startDrag();

Comment: yes, exactly, also - if you will make the content of the drag_1 not accessible to mouseevents then your code will work without modifications - this is becuase the "guts" has hijacked the mouseevent. so try drag_1.mouseChildren = false;